# KernelOops - suspend/resume failure on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: kernel, login, display, performance

I have a Dell computer, installed with Ubuntu Linux 14.04.5 LTS. Sometimes my computer gets very slow that I have to restart it. Occasionally, no log in screen shows up. When I press the power button to shut it off and then turn it back on, the error message says:

> KernelOops; Suspend/resume failure.

Below are some more details:

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde GL [FirePro W4100] 
           X.Org: 1.17.1 drivers: ati,fglrx (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,radeon) Resolution: 1920x1080@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: AMD FirePro W4100 (FireGL V) Graphics Adapter GLX Version: 4.5.13416 - CPC FireGL 15.30.1028
```

- LSB Version:

  ```
  core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:security-4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch
  Distributor ID: Ubuntu
  Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
  Release:    14.04
  Codename:   trusty
  ```
- versions: Ubuntu 3.19.0-80.88~14.04.1-generic 3.19.8-ckt22
- content of `susres.2018-04-29_15:15:11.537481.crash`:

  ```
  ProblemType: KernelOops
  Annotation: This occured during a previous suspend and prevented it from resuming properly.
  Architecture: amd64
  Date: Sun Apr 29 15:14:48 2018
  DistroRelease: Ubuntu 14.04
  ExecutablePath: /usr/share/apport/apportcheckresume
  ExecutableTimestamp: 1510701014
  Failure: suspend/resume
  InterpreterPath: /usr/bin/python3.4
  Package: linux-image-3.19.0-80-generic 3.19.0-80.88~14.04.1
  ```

Comment: You came to the right place! However, in order for us to help you, we will need more information. Please [edit] your question and tell us exactly what the problem is. When does it happen? What exactly do you see? Does the machine never resume from suspend? Does it not suspend at all? Does it resume but the screen stays off? Something else? What kind of computer is this (laptop? Which one? Desktop?). What graphics card? Try installing `inxi` (`sudo apt install inxi`) and add the output of `inxi -G` to your question.

Comment: Regarding the question "don't know how to attach" about your log files: To add log files to your question, open the log files in a text editor, and then copy/paste the log file contents into your question as an edit, and indicate which log file(s) it(/they) are.  There is no 'attachments' system here.

Comment: Or, if the log files are too large to paste inside your question use a pastebin system such as https://paste.ubuntu.com or https://paste.debian.net.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question for *each separate issue*, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.